# How to sum based on conditions in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

Table1 is having fields

id, user_id, main_view_id, master_view_id

Table2

id, user_id, view_id, total

I need sum of total for main_view, master_view

final result i want

id, user_id, total_master, total_main

I did query something like this which is working fine

```
SELECT user_id, 
SUM(CASE 
    WHEN `table1`.`main_view_id` = `table2`.`view_id` 
    THEN `total` 
    ELSE 0 ) as total_main, 
SUM(CASE 
    WHEN `table1`.`master_view_id` = `table2`.`view_id` 
    THEN `total` 
    ELSE 0 ) as total_master
from table1
LEFT JOIN ON table2.user_id = table1.user_id
GROUP BY table1.user_id
```

This query is quite slow while processing, as i have lots of fields with 5 more tables.

Is there any alternative to do this

Thanks

Comment: You're missing the table name in `LEFT JOIN`. It should be `LEFT JOIN table2 ON ...`

Comment: It would be helpful to include example input and output.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: USe `EXPLAIN` to see the query plan. It will tell you if indexes are being used.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly direct query so I wonder if your view_ids are indexed?  2nd attempt:

```
select
  user_id,
  (select sum(total) from table2 where table1.user = table2.user and `table1`.`main_view_id` = `table2`.`view_id`) as total_main,
  (select sum(total) from table2 where table1.user = table2.user and `table1`.`master_view_id` = `table2`.`view_id`) as total_master
from table1
group by 1;
```

Comment: This will not produce the correct result because you'll multiply one of the sums by the number of matches to the other condition.